# Docker in Docker, Building docker agents in a docker contained Jenkins Server

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-in-docker

I am currently running a Jenkins with Docker. When trying to build docker apps, i am facing some doubt on if i should use Docker in Docker (Dind) by binding the /var/run/docker.sock file or by installing another instance of docker in my Jenkins Docker. I actually saw that previously, it was discouraged to use something else than the docker.sock.

I don't actually understand why we should use something else than the docker daemon from the host apart from not polluting it.

sources : https://itnext.io/docker-in-docker-521958d34efd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution for "jenkins in docker container needs docker" case is to add your host as a node(slave) in jenkins. This will make every build step (literally everything) run in your host machine. It took me a month to find perfect setup.

**Mount docker socket in jenkins container:** You will lose context. The files you want to COPY inside image is located inside workspace in jenkins container and your docker is running at host. COPY fails for sure.

**Install docker client in jenkins container:** You have to alter official jenkins image. Adds complexity. And you will lose context too.

**Add your host as jenkins node:** Perfect. You have the contex. No altering the official image.

Comment: Yes this is what i actually do but the problem is, all of those built images by jenkins get stacked up in my host machine which is not ideal for me. I am actually looking at this https://hub.docker.com/_/docker but i am still figuring out how to install jenkins on top of it.

Comment: Why don't you delete images after you built them? It's better to push them to a private registry (you can have it via docker) and delete from host afterwards.

Comment: actually stupid of me for not thinking about adding a step in my pipeline which deletes the images. Thanks for the hint tho. Marking as solved

Answer (score -2):

Without completely understanding why you would need to use Docker in Docker - I suspect you need to meet some special requirements considering the environment in which you build the actual image, may I suggest you multistage building of docker images? You might find it useful as it enables you to first build the building environment and then build the actual image (hence the name 'multistage-building). Check it out here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: the problem relies first on using docker commands withing the jenkins container.