# Docker in Docker for Jenkins slave node is not working

Tags: jenkins

I tried to build a docker image in a docker. the image was properly built in the previous pipeline. but now it gives the below error.

```
+ docker build -t trabeya/testdocker:15 .
time="2021-03-18T07:36:20Z" level=error msg="failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This is the docker image that is used for jenkins slave node.

```
FROM jenkins/inbound-agent:0.1

USER root

#install maven
RUN wget https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz
RUN mkdir /opt/maven
RUN tar xzvf apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz  --directory /opt/maven
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/
ENV MAVEN_HOME=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3 

#install docker
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install docker.io -y
RUN docker --version
```

Appreciate it if someone can guide me for a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Did you mount your host machine's `docker.sock` into the container that builds the image? That's required if you want to perform any docker tasks from inside your docker container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker in Docker, Building docker agents in a docker contained Jenkins Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042817/docker-in-docker-building-docker-agents-in-a-docker-contained-jenkins-server)